# How to import table with mix of text and image metadata with IMPORTHTML and/or IMPORTXML?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import tables with a mixture of text and images into Google Sheets with IMPORTHTML and/or IMPORTXML function.

The tables I'm trying to import are the 'Equipment' tables under the 'Advancement' section from multiple sites like this: https://stt.wiki/wiki/Xindi_%27Prisoner%27_Archer.

The number of stars at each item in the table represents a "level" from 1 ("Common") to 5 ("Legendary"), with no stars representing level 0 ("Basic"). The image metadata contains the level description. Example for "Legendary" level:

```
<img alt="Legendary" src="/w/images/thumb/b/b5/StarItem.png/15px-StarItem.png" title="Legendary" width="15" height="15" style="vertical-align: sub" srcset="/w/images/thumb/b/b5/StarItem.png/23px-StarItem.png 1.5x, /w/images/thumb/b/b5/StarItem.png/30px-StarItem.png 2x">
```

My problem is to include the level information in the import, either as images or as image metadata.

My ultimate goal is a table like this (created manually):

[image: desired outcome]

(columns E and I with URLs are optional).

---

**IMPORTHTML:**

First I tried to import with IMPORTHTML, cell A1 contains the URL (see above) *(please note that I have to use semicolon in formulas due to local settings)*:

```
=IMPORTHTML(A1; "table"; 4)
```

This gives me this table:

[image: import result for above code]

Unfortunately, the "stars" from the original table are not imported.

1) So the first question is: Is there a way to include the images from a table with IMPORTHTML method? Or alternatively metadata from the images?

---

**IMPORTXML:**

I then tried to use IMPORTXML to get just the missing level data:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1; "//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[3]/tbody/tr/td/span/img[1]/@alt").
```

The IMPORTHTML gave me 40 items in total, but with this IMPORTXML I only get 37 values for item levels. This is because with my IMPORTXML method I don't get information on the "Basic" items, that is the items without stars.

So now I have a list of 37 levels and a table with 40 items, but no logical connection between them. The list of levels would need entries (could be blank cells) for the basic items at the correct positions in the list to make the assignmant between items and levels possible.

2) So my second question is: For the IMPORTXML method, is there any way to get a result with the same number of cells in Google sheets as in the original table, even when for some cells of the original table the XPATH doesn't match? In this case the import could give an empty cell instead.
In the example this would give me a list of 40 cells, 3 of which would be empty.

---

Other solutions with Google Sheets are welcome, too.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: The answer by player0 solves the problem, but as it is (for me) harder to understand, I've marked the answer by E.Wiest as solution. Still, both are beautiful examples of how to use IMPORTHTML/IMPORTXML and XPATH logic. Learned a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath solution (6 are used, check yellow cells) :

[image]

[Star.Treck.Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/130gUcEJg-TXyILIuaWN1WFRA8rt0EHxE0YuMYTPTKAk/edit?usp=sharing)

First we get the structure of the table with IMPORTHTML. Then with XPath, we get the ids, members names and levels of everyone with a star (i.e a rank). Then we get the ids and members names of everyone (with and without a star). We VLOOKUP to build the levels table (see join.levels). No star >> "Basic". We fetch the urls. Finally, we build our final table with CONCAT (ids+names to secure the join).

Comment: Thanks, I think this is just what I'm looking for. Took me a while to understand the "preceding" in the XPATH, though.

Comment: The URLs are all the same, though. How can I fix that?

Comment: OK. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

would this satisfy you:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4:B13&C4:C13, {
 IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title/preceding::td[@class='ItemRight'][1]")&
 IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title/preceding::a[1]"),
 VLOOKUP(IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title"),
 {"Common",     "★", "", "", "", "";
  "Uncommon",   "★", "★", "", "", "";
  "Rare",       "★", "★", "★", "", "";
  "Super Rare", "★", "★", "★", "★", "";
  "Legendary",  "★", "★", "★", "★", "★"}, 
 {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0)}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0)))
```

[image]

or with original stars:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IMAGE(SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B4:B13&C4:C13, {
 IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title/preceding::td[@class='ItemRight'][1]")&
 IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title/preceding::a[1]"), 
 VLOOKUP(IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title"), 
 {"Common",     "★", "", "", "", "";
  "Uncommon",   "★", "★", "", "", "";
  "Rare",       "★", "★", "★", "", "";
  "Super Rare", "★", "★", "★", "★", "";
  "Legendary",  "★", "★", "★", "★", "★"}, 
 {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0)}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0)), "★", 
 "https://stt.wiki/w/images/thumb/b/b5/StarItem.png/15px-StarItem.png"), 3))
```

[image: 0]

---

**original:**

[image]

---

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UO1B0DUFVakaBLF_cFXrY_cIr0DQc_B7CT0ztafrY5k/edit#gid=58426195)

Comment: That is quite impressive! It took me a while to try to understand your formulas. I think I get the general idea, but there are still some parts I don't understand, especially with the REGEXREPLACE and the QUERY parts. In D4 I don't understand why you use "offset 5" in the query, and I don't understand the replacement part with the special characters: "♦$1♥". Maybe you could elaborate?

Comment: As I don't fully understand your formulae, I've marked E.Wiest's answer as solution. But yours sure looks impressive and I will try to understand this solution as well to use it in the future.

Comment: Just found that there are two stars missing in the table: at the level 60 and level 90 item, respectively.

Comment: @Morphan `offset 5` is used just for the "cosmetic" purpose to skip some previous metadata stuff that got imported as well but as now tested it even holds without the `offset 5`

Comment: @Morphan `♦$1♥` is a regex way how to append stuff only where needed - in this case its `(\d+:)` which translates as: "group of numbers followed by colon" (parenthesis makes it the group). then `$1` means return group so the whole thing translates as: "return first group as it is and add ♦ before and ♥ after the group"

Comment: Thank you for the explanations and the fix of star counts. But now there is a new error with star count of level 90 item in the last column.

Comment: Hi @player0 I tested this one which works on the developer tools `//*[@id="zone1"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]`  but not in google sheet. Output https://i.imgur.com/VjoZ210.png
xpath https://i.imgur.com/tY2YAnB.png
url https://www.onelook.com/thesaurus/?s=alluring Any suggestion to get it to work? thanks.