# Google Sheets IMPORTXML: How to identify correct table by header instead of table index?

Tags: xpath, indexing, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import data from tables into Google Sheets with IMPORTXML, and I already have working example for one table:

```
IMPORTXML($A1, "//table[3]/tbody//span/img[1]/@title")
```

A1 containing the URL.

My problem is, I have to do this for several different URLs. While the tables always have the same structure, the table itself can be at an arbitrary position on the website. Therefore I cannot rely on the table index like in "table[3]", but have to find the correct table by its title/header instead.

Here are two example URLs:

- https://stt.wiki/wiki/Xindi_%27Prisoner%27_Archer
- [https://stt.wiki/wiki/UFP President Ra-ghoratreii](https://stt.wiki/wiki/UFP%20President%20Ra-ghoratreii)

I want to import data from the "Equipment" tables in the "Advancement" section.

The above example with "table[3]" works for the first URL, but for the second URL the table index is 4, so I would have to use "table[4]".

I guess I have to identify the correct table by its header entries, in this case "Equip Rank".

1. Is there any way to include the header information in the IMPORTXML
   query for the table index?
2. Or alternatively to retrieve the correct
   table index number within Google Sheets?
3. A third way might be to make use of the section title "Advancement" in the XPATH query.

As I will have quite a lot of calculations on my sheet, I'd prefer a "calculation time friendly" way for the import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Star Trek strikes again. Solution with IMPORTXML to determine the position of the table, then IMPORTHTML to fetch the data.

[image: STrek]

[Star.Trek.P2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/130gUcEJg-TXyILIuaWN1WFRA8rt0EHxE0YuMYTPTKAk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks again. I just don't understand why in your example the table position for the first URL is "4" whereas in my working example it is "3". Both examples return valid results though.

Comment: And for those wondering what E.Wiest is referring to with "Star Trek strikes again": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878556/how-to-import-table-with-mix-of-text-and-image-metadata-with-importhtml-and-or-i

Comment: It is table[3] of a div element not of the whole webpage. The table containing the data is the fifth table of the webpage. GoogleSheets parses webpages its own way. I suppose the first table "Call for help" isn't parsed so n°5 becomes n°4...

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
=importxml(A1,"//h2[span[@id='Advancement']]/following-sibling::table[@class='wikitable']")
```